# Django filter().exists always returns false

Tags: python, django

I've started making a website in Django and I'm attempting to write unit tests for it, however, I'm unable to get one this unit test to pass.

```
def test_email_already_in_use(self):
    user_email = 'testing_email@testing.com'
    password = 'testing_password'
    User.objects.create_user(username=user_email, password=password)
    tmp = User.objects.filter(email=user_email).exists()
    form_data = {'email': user_email, 'password': password}

    with self.assertRaises(ValidationError):
        form = UserForm(data=form_data)
        form.clean_email()
```

The problem is that tmp is always false (tmp is just used to help me debug without having to step any further. The exists check is done in clean_email normally). However, when I attempt to create a new user with an existing email when the website running the code run properly. I'm obviously missing something with how create_user works.

This is the code that properly checks against an email already being in use when I attempt to create a new user with the same email.

```
def clean_email(self):
    email = self.data['email']

    if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
        raise ValidationError("Email already in use")
    if len(email) > 100:
        raise ValidationError("Email length exceeds 100")

    return email
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using django.contrib.auth.models.User, the username and email fields are different. The following line of code does not create an object with the given email address in the email field

```
 User.objects.create_user(username=user_email, password=password)
```

Thus your exists query should really be

```
  tmp = User.objects.filter(username=user_email).exists()
```

Comment: That's a pretty dumb mistake on my part, thank you for pointing that out. I also realised that it worked in my view because I had email=user_email which I missed in the unit test.

Comment: Happens to everyone